# PHP - MySQL server has gone away in - always happens in 1 function?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to solve a issue that's been going on for a long time but I'm unable to really figure out that the actual issue is.

I keep getting the following error:

```
[19-Dec-2020 22:07:31 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away in /home/user12345/domains/example.com/public_html/sys/lib.php:266
Stack trace:
#0 /home/user12345/domains/example.com/public_html/sys/lib.php(266): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/user12345/domains/example.com/public_html/sys/lib.php(203): websiteClass->isTitleInDatabase('update', 'TEST06951')
#2 /home/user12345/domains/example.com/public_html/sys/lib.php(326): websiteClass->importData('update', 'TEST06951')
#3 /home/user12345/domains/example.com/public_html/crond/process.php(4): websiteClass->updateQueueDaemonProcess2()
#4 {main}
  thrown in /home/user12345/domains/example.com/public_html/sys/lib.php on line 266

[19-Dec-2020 22:41:10 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away in /home/user12345/domains/example.com/public_html/sys/lib.php:266
Stack trace:
#0 /home/user12345/domains/example.com/public_html/sys/lib.php(266): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/user12345/domains/example.com/public_html/sys/lib.php(410): websiteClass->isTitleInDatabase('update', 'TEST02952')
#2 /home/user12345/domains/example.com/public_html/crond/scraper.php(4): websiteClass->updateQueueDaemonScraper()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home/user12345/domains/example.com/public_html/sys/lib.php on line 266
```

This error appears to be completely random everytime.

Looking at the error, it seems to be happening in this function:

```
public function isTitleInDatabase($database, $titleid) {
    $titleid = $this->titleid($titleid);
    
    if(is_null($titleid)) {
        return true;
    } elseif($database == 'tmdb') {
        $check = $this->query("SELECT 1 FROM tmdb WHERE titleid=:titleid LIMIT 1");
        if($check->execute(array(':titleid'=>$titleid . '_00'))) {
            if($check->rowCount() > 0) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    } elseif($database == 'update') {
        $json = $this->apiData('update', $titleid);
        
        if($json !== 0) {
            $check = $this->query("SELECT 1 FROM update WHERE titleid=:titleid AND version=:version LIMIT 1");
            if($check->execute(array(':titleid'=>$titleid,':version'=>$json['version']))) {
                if($check->rowCount() > 0) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            } else {
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 2;
}
```

This functions works fine in most cases, but every day I open the error log and there appear to be new errors, similar to the ones above - always coming from this function.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Check the log for the mysql daemon.

Comment: @Barmar This function runs in a cronjob

Comment: So? Find the time that PHP got the error, then check the mysql daemon's log for the reason for the crash at that time.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the PHP code, the queries are very simple. But something is causing the mysql daemon to crash, you need to investigate that.

Comment: I've checked my hosting panel but I don't think they keep logs of mysql? This is the only log I have

Comment: Contact the hosting provider to find out how you can check the mysqld logs. There's not enough information your post to know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me. It was bad characters passing to SQL query. Special characters and Cyrilic characters do that in my case. I have to change UTF8 to UTF8m4 (real UTF8)